# MaterializeCss Issue: Can't open a tooltip using methods

Tags: materialize

I hope you all are having a good day. I have a little issue, coud you help me? I can't open a tooltip by methods. I have in HTML

```
<div id="filter-btn" class="filter-btn right waves-effect waves-blue tooltipped"
    data-position="left"
    data-tooltip="¡Ahora puedes filtrar por tipo de resultado!">
         <i class="material-icons">filter_list</i>
</div>
```

I initialized it and it works moving the mouse over it, but when I try to open it with the `open()` method:

```
var tooltip = M.Tooltip.getInstance(document.getElementById('filter-btn'));
    tooltip.open();
```

Does not work, but if check the status with `tooltip.isOpen` it return `true` despite is not showing nothing.

The initialization is there:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltipped');
    var instances = M.Tooltip.init(elems, {enterDelay:50});
});
```